# What is Global Wide Area Network (GWAN)?

Tags: network

Recently I encounter with a new term [Global Wide Area Network (GWAN)](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/GWAN).

[LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network), [WAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_area_network) is common, but not GWAN. I've been searching around on the net but couldn't find the answer. So, I guess someone from here must have the answer.

What is Global Wide Area Network (GWAN) and the difference between it and normal WAN?1

Comment: We need some context to your question. Where did you see this term?  Can you provide a link?

Comment: Those terms mean different things to different people, and they often require context. For example, LAN can mean a broadcast domain, a physical cable plant, a smal network in a single building or close group of buildings, etc., and it all depends on the context. There is no standard that defines what the terms mean.

Comment: @RonTrunk link already been provided on the post above. It's under Global Wide Area Network (GWAN). Here is the link again https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/GWAN

Comment: I don't think it's a commonly (much less universally) used term in the industry.  Is there context beyond freedictionary - like a paper, vendor materials or similar?

Comment: Historically, *WAN* wasn't used to refer to the Internet, just to a network with very long links. Likely, they wanted to reflect that but *GWAN* isn't a common term.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The Internet is full of apparently technical terms have a meaning only to the person who coined it, often for marketing reasons.  There is no generally agreed upon definition for this term.  You're free to define it any way you like.

Answer (score 1):

There is a such thing as a GAN (Global Area Network) defined as something similar to a network covering an unlimited geographical area. I Assume the GWAN is the same thing. A WAN (Wide area network) is a large network spread over a large geographical region. Combining WAN and GAN int GWAN for Global WAN seems a little odd, but I assume wherever you came across the term it is a unique term created by the author to help illustrate a GAN. I could consider my company a GAN that utilizes multiple physical and logical connections to span the globe.